# biblatex: how to reference an interviewer

Tags: biblatex

I would like to cite an interview of François Hartog by Julien Tassel for the Revue de Sociologie pratique. My basic .bib entry looks like this:

```
@article{HartogEntretien,$
    author = {François Hartog},$
    title = {Les usages publics du passé en temps de présentisme},$
    journal = {Sociologies pratiques},$
    date = {2014},$
    volume = {2},$
    number = {29},$
    doi = {10.3917/sopr.029.0011},$
    pages = {11–17}$
}
```

I don't know however how to quote Julien Tassel, the interviewer. I thought that

```
    editor = {Julien Tassel},$
    editortype = {interviewer},$
```

might help, but there is no interviewer option for editortype and I could'nt find any relative entry in the doc. "entretien avec Julien Tassel" in the author field is a workaround, is there something that fits better to biblatex spirit?

EDIT: I don't know if my MWE is good enough, maybe I should add that I am using biblatex with a verbose citation style

Comment: You might find the `@misc` entry type a flexible way to deal with interviews (if you do not want to create your own custom entry type). Only the `date` and `title` fields are strictly necessary, though `author`/`editor` is normally required. The `howpublished` (literal) field is where the flexibility really comes into play.

Comment: Here it would probably be easiest to put something like "interview by Julien Tassel" into the `titleaddon` or `note` field. Of course you could create a new field `inteerviewer` and implement its use, but that is probably massive overkill if you have only a few interviews in your bibliography.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Since I have just one interview I will use the titleaddon field, but I keep the @misc in mind for the future…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an interview published as an `@article` you can probably just use the `titleaddon` or `note` fields to specify the additional information.

If you have more interviews, you could think about creating a new name field `interviewer` and use that. That will require a new datamodel field and some changes to `biblatex` macros or drivers.